# Generated number on python open on notepad?

Tags: python

Basically i have a code which inputs 2 random numbers for strength and skill. These 2 inputs i would like to be saved on a notepad. The number generates a random number for strength and skill and i would like the number to saved on the notepad every time. So when i look back on the notepad it shows the last number which were generated. This is my code so far:

```
import random

playname1 = str(input("Enter player one name"))
print("Welcome",playname1)

strength1 = random.randint(1,12)

strength2 = random.randint(1,4)

strength3 = (strength1/strength2)

strength4 = round(strength3)

strength5= (10+strength4)

print ("Your strength is...",strength5)

skill1 = random.randint(1,12)

skill2 = random.randint(1,4)

skill3 = (skill1/skill2)

skill4 = round(skill3)

skill5= (10+skill4)

print ("Your skill is...",skill5)
```

The next part of the code i would like to be the two numbers for strength and skill to be save on a notepad.

Comment: By "notepad", do you mean "text file", e.g. a file you could open in Notepad?

Comment: You already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179180/save-python-data-onto-a-notepad-file. You can edit that question instead of starting a new one and fragmenting things.

Comment: I'm kind of new to this

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is

```
import os
strength5,skill5 =10,20
with open("data.txt") as f:
    f.write("%s %s"%(strength5, skill5))
os.startfile("data.txt")
```

assuming I understand what you mean by "save on notepad"  (eg. you dont mean write it down on a sticky note?)

Comment: when i try it it says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python CW\q2.py", line 23, in <module>
    print >> f, strength5, skill5
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'builtin_function_or_method' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'
>>>

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the version of Python you are using, but according to your syntax, I assume you are using Python3? First of all, you don't need to do `str(input(...))` - that's already a str.

In Python3, the correct way to write to a file is:

```
with open('text.txt', 'w') as f:
    print('a sentence', file=f) // this will add a new line at the end automatically
    // or you can do:
    // f.write('a sentence\n')
    // since write doesn't add new line automatically, you need to explicitly type \n
```

Comment: How would i make it so it prints whatever the random numbers for strength and skill are?

Comment: @user3380211 `print('strength: {}, skill: {}'.format(strength, skill), file=f)` assuming `strength` and `skill` in `format()` are variables where you store the two numbers.

Comment: I tried it and didn't work for me, could your write the code exactly out please?

Comment: @user3380211 I can't just write the code exactly out for you. This is not a copy & paste website. What is the error message?

Comment: Basically the second line of code i don't no what the write.

Comment: @user3380211 Ok. So `print('something', file=f)` will print something into the file you just opened - in my case, `text.txt`. What `format` does is that it inserts items in the str replacing the `{}`. So let's say `var1 = 1, var2 = 2`, `print('a: {}, b: {}'.format(var1, var2), file=f)` will print 'a: 1, b: 2' into `text.txt`

Comment: I got to:    with open('player1.txt', 'w') as f:
    print('strength5,skill5', file=f)
But when i open the notepad file it says strength5,skill5 when i would want it to be the random 2 numbers generated...

Comment: @user3380211 Because you didn't format the str. It should be `print('{}, {}'.format(strength5, skill5), file=f)`

Comment: It worked, thank you so mate for putting up with me thanks :)

Comment: @user3380211 You need to try by yourself and think more first :)

Comment: @user3380211 Accepting my answer is probably the best way to say thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in your initialization.

```
f = open('output.txt', 'w')
```

Note that this opens it in write mode so all previous data are erased. If you want to append use

```
f = opr('output.txt', 'a')
```

Now just write the text data

```
datatxt = ' '.join(str(strength5), str(skill5))
f.write(datatxt)
```

After you completely finish

```
f.close()
```